# How to connect Intel XDK app to Oracle database?

Tags: database, oracle, mobile, cross-platform, intel-xdk

We have a website that stores data in an Oracle database. We are now building a cross-platform app that will fetch some of that data from the database. For this purpose, we are using the Intel XDK.

How do I connect and fetch/ insert/ update data from the Oracle database?

For the fetching purpose, I was thinking of generating JSON data from a Java file and then accessing the same from the

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way is having JSON REST APIs implemented on the backend for accessing and posting data. Then just make ajax calls in XDK app to fetch and update data.